# Running spark application with two different java versions

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any way I can run the **Spark3** application with **two different java versions** for example **java8** and **java11**?

I have tried the following command but it is picking the default java version i.e java8.

```
spark-shell \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.17.0.8-2.el7_9.x86_64/ \
--conf spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.17.0.8-2.el7_9.x86_64/
```

Comment: What about changing your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable before running your spark-shell?

Comment: i have exported JAVA_HOME before launching the spark-shell and there is no luck

Comment: @RangaReddy is the issue resolved ? if yes plz post your answer

Comment: Hi @abhinay not yet resolved.

Comment: @RangaReddy, I am updated the spark-shell file with jdk8 from default jdk11 path.. it worked for me.

Comment: Can you share the steps or where exactly you have changed and ran the job